# How to get the coordinates of Hyperlink in UIWebview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, uipopovercontroller, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm loading the pdf (Having multiple Hyperlinks) document in `UIWebview`. I have to show `UIPopover` over hyperlinks dynamically.

I'm able to capture the coordinates of hyperlink using TapGesture Action method

```
- (void)tapAction:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender    
{
    self.point = [sender locationInView:self.myWebView];  
}
```

And presenting the `UIPopover` over hyperlink by using below method

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *rqstUrl = [request URL];
    if (([[rqstUrl scheme] isEqualToString: @"https"] || [[rqstUrl scheme] isEqualToString: @"http"]) && (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked))
    {
        [self.myWebView stopLoading];
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(self.point.x,self.point.y-5, 5, 5);
        UIPopoverController *popController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:contentViewController];
        popController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(500, 200);
        self.popController = popController;
        self.popController.delegate =self;
        UIPopoverArrowDirection direction = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp|UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown;
        self.popController.popoverLayoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, rect.origin.x, 1, 1);
        [self.popController presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:webView permittedArrowDirections:direction animated:YES];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

But the problem is if I tapped in two different locations within 1 or 2 seconds like First Tap is **On Hyperlink** and Second Tap is on "somewhere else in `UIWebview`", `UIPopover` is presenting at second tap location only not in hyperlink location. 
I have to show `UIPopover` based on the Hyperlink position only, not in other location.How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

### Use an overlay view

1. Replace your method to register the tap location by an **overlay** with a tap through. `UITapGestureRecognizer` has these limitations:

   - When a tap occurs outside of an hyperlink, it does registers its location, thanks to the `UITapGestureRecognizer`.
   - Unfortunately, a `UIWebview` Hyperlink taps take precedence over the gesture recognizer, and you never get the `centroid`. This is the real problem, causing the popover to appear misplaced.
2. `UIPopoverController` is deprecated in iOS 9.

   > "UIPopoverController is deprecated. Popovers are now implemented as UIViewController presentations. Use a modal presentation style of UIModalPresentationPopover and UIPopoverPresentationController."
3. `tapAction` and `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` are not coupled, and can occur independently of each other. Furthermore, they are basically mutually exclusive.

[image]

Use the **overlay** to register location in that view, and tap-though to the views underneath. **If** your overlay and web view have the same frame, you can use the tap position interchangeably. The overlay will guarantee tight coupling, and the rest of your method will work as designed.

```
class TapOverlayView: UIView {
    var centroid:CGRect = CGRect.zero

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        centroid = CGRect(origin: point, size: CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))
        return nil // tap through
    }
}
```

**Delegate**

```
extension ViewController: UIWebViewDelegate {
    public func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        let rqstUrl = request.url

        if( rqstUrl!.scheme?.contains("http"))! && ( .linkClicked == navigationType) {
            webView.stopLoading()

            let contentViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popover")
            contentViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
            contentViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 40)

            if let popController = contentViewController.popoverPresentationController {
                popController.permittedArrowDirections = .down
                popController.sourceView = webView
                popController.sourceRect = CGRect(origin: tap.centroid.origin, size: CGSize.zero)
                present(contentViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

---

► Find this solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-32670551) and additional details on [Swift Recipes](http://swiftarchitect.com/recipes/#SO-32670551).

Comment: It's work fine, but how to get point in the middle of word which clicked?